# Improper SQL Server statistics

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have simple situation with large table and clustered index with 3 int fields. When I filter with first 2, the estimated number of rows is improper because statistics show wrong numbers. This is tested on SQL Server 2019 CU12. Same problem is on all SQL Server version. The lowest I tested is SQL 2008 with all service packs.

Here is my SQL code (example)

```
create table dbo.glp_test (NagId bigint not null, Lp bigint not null,Id bigint not null, opis varchar(200), CONSTRAINT BK_glp_test PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(NagId, Lp, id))
GO
create function dbo.genNum(@start int, @end int)
returns @t table (num int not null identity(1,1))
begin
  while @start<=@end
  begin
    insert into @t default values
    set @start = @start+1;
  end

  return;
end
GO
insert into dbo.glp_test (NagId, lp, Id, opis)
select s.Num, c.Num, c.Num*c2.Num, convert(varchar(100), c.Num*c2.Num)
  from dbo.genNum(1,10000) s
  cross apply dbo.genNum(1,30) c
  cross apply dbo.genNum(1,30) c2 
GO
update statistics glp_test with fullscan
GO
dbcc show_statistics('glp_test','BK_glp_test')
GO
-- select [rows]*[All density]
select 9000000*3.333333E-06 -- 29,999997 - correct
GO
update statistics glp_test
GO
dbcc show_statistics('glp_test','BK_glp_test')
GO
-- select [rows]*[All density]
select 9000000*8.609557E-05 -- 774,86013 - dramatically incorrect
GO
```

Now if I query table glp_test with exact values of field 1 and field 2 then estimated number of rows is wrong. The estimation should be close to 30. Updating statistics with fullscan fixes problem, but this is not a solution. How to solve this problem?

```
declare @Nagid bigint, @Lp bigint
select * from dbo.glp_test where NagID = @NagId and Lp = @Lp
```

Comment: FYI I really recommend against those functions. Multi-line table value functions are known to perform poorly, and one with a `WHILE` is going to be dreadful for performance.

Comment: Function genNum is just technical and has nothing in common with statistics problem

Comment: CU13 exists for SQL Server 2019, perhaps any bug you experience might be fixed already. The problem could be with stale statistics however, perhaps updating the statistics solves the problem?

Comment: Simple updating statistics does not solve problem. Only fullscan does. Since problem is even in SQL 2008 I don't think they solve it in CU13.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this has to do with the default sampling that happens when update stats runs without the WITH FULLSCAN. See this [link](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/auto-update-stats-default-sampling-test/) where Joe Sack shows sampling percentages in a test he did. Notice that the default sample rate drops off considerably.

Comment: FULLSCAN takes much more time and resources. From my point of view this sounds like a bug since I would expect values between 0 and maximum number per first two fields (0-30). Any value that is more than this is invalid for any sample it takes.